# How to add/remove hidden class

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor tag I'd like to remove/add a hidden class from but for some reason my simple if else statement isn't working and the "Reset" stays shown. I want it so that when there's text in the input it shows but when it is empty it doesn't show. I haven't been able to get it to work. I can provide more if needed

```
const search = document.querySelector('.frm-control');
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset')
if (search != "") {
  reset.classList.remove('hidden');
} else {
  reset.classList.add('hidden');
}
console.log(reset)
console.log(search)

reset.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  // x();
  // e.preventDefault();


  // const row = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-display');
  // row.classList.add('hidden');
  // search.innerHTML = "";
})
```

At first I thought to add the condition into my event listener but that also wasn't working

HTML: https://codepen.io/ahassan77/pen/QWWBKxo

Comment: `search` will never equal `""`, because it’s never a string.

Comment: Like this, I guess? https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/bGGjwzz Main issues: 1) removing/adding the class needs to go inside the `input` event for the text field 2) the text field contents is accessed using `.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the class inside the *input* event handler function of the element.

**Please Note:** To reset the text from the input element you have to use the `value` property not the `innerHTML`.

Try the following way:

```js
const search = document.querySelector('.frm-control');
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset')

search.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  if (this.value.trim() != "") {
    reset.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    reset.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});

reset.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  // x();
  // e.preventDefault();
  // const row = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-display');
  search.value = "";
  reset.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form class="frm-filter">
  <div class="frm-group">
    <a class="reset" href="#">Reset</a>
    <input class="frm-control" type="text" id="filter" name="filter" placeholder="tag filter" />
  </div>
</form>
```